# scrollbar plugin doesn't always work, is there a preload or something I can do?

Tags: jquery

So here is the site: http://graysonearle.com/newtest/#prettyPhoto/6/
That takes you to a little window with a sidebar housing some images. I'm using lionbar, which is great, but it only works 50% of the time. This is not a typical web problem in my experience. What would cause a script to randomly not function? Is there a tag I can throw in there that makes sure a script is loaded properly?
Just reload it until you see it work/not work.
Also does it have something to do with the way I am invoking the plugin?

```
<script>
$('#sidebar').lionbars();
</script>
```

Just before the /body tag. Would it be more reliable if I did it another way?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can see what's happening..? Also how do we recognise it 'working' versus 'not working,' what does lionbar do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presented problem is due to the script being initialized before the images are loaded.

Since the plug-in checks for the "need" of scrollbars:

**Line 371 of lionbars.js**

```
// check for vertical scrollbars
if (el.get(0).scrollHeight > el.get(0).clientHeight) {
  addVScroll = true;
  // setVScrollbarWidth(el);
}
```

You need to make sure the images are loaded before calling the script.

I would suggest a script from a fellow stackoverflow user, that will run the lionbars function after the images are loaded:

[GitHub page link for jQuery waitForImages!](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages)

**e.g.,**

```
$('#sidebar').waitForImages(function() {

    // All images are loaded, initialize the scroll bar plug-in
    $('#sidebar').lionbars();
});
```

**Note:**

The reason why the script sometimes works, is because sometimes the images are already cached by the browser and they get placed on the document before the script gets initialized.